# Create a dicom print server using python

Tags: python, dicom

I am trying to create a dicom print server using python. As client,I am using QuantorMeddemo software which can act as an x-ray machine scanning software. So far I managed to create a PACS server using pynetdicom and have received dcm data from QUantor Med.But that doesnt register as a print server(I guess) and only works when I use the option to send my study to some PACS server and not when I use the print option in that software.
Now my question is,is there any library that can help me create a print server/dicom print server?

Answer (score 0):

You can try dcmtk whick have a print SCP:

[dcmtk](http://dicom.offis.de/dcmtk.php.en)